# Aggressively fsck a disk before install

Tags: debian, system-installation, fsck

I have an old HP Athlon machine I use for testing software under the old processor. We have frequent brown outs, and after the last one the disk was a mess. It was so bad I could not run `fsck` and dispatch all the problems. I performed a fresh install of the OS, but I'm still getting `fsck` complaints.

I'd like to try one last time to reload Linux before condemning the hard drive or machine. After the filesystem is created but before the install occurs, I'd like an aggressive `fsck` performed to mark suspect blocks as bad.

The disk is large (about 500 GB) and a Debian 8 distro is relatively small (8-12 GB is usually more than enough), so I don't care if good blocks get marked as bad. I also like the GUI install, but I'm not married to it.

I have two questions:

1. Does Debian 8 provide a choice to perform an `fsck` before installing the base system? If so, where is it? If not, then what is the process?
2. Does `fsck` have a setting to control how aggressively blocks are marked as bad? If so, what is it? If not, then what can be used?

---

***EDIT***: the machine is an HP5850. Entering the BIOS, navigating to Storage and then Drive Protection System (DPS) Self-test resulted in DPS recommending replace the drive. DPS did not provide any statistics, so I'm not sure the extent of the damage.

Considering I can purchase an [old] new SATA II drive for $12 USD, I'm just going to replace it. There's no sense in wasting time or energy on it.

---

The related references are as follows. Neither question appears to be addressed.

- [`fsck` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)
- [Chapter 6. Using the Debian Installer | 6.3. Using Individual Components](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s03.html.en#di-partition)

Comment: Why not [SpinRite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpinRite)?

Comment: If you have any bad blocks at all, the entire drive is physically failing and shouldn't be used.

Comment: "Aggressively fsck a disk" looks so dirty...

Answer (score 19):

1. *"Does Debian 8 provide a choice to perform an fsck before installing the base system? If so, where is it? If not, then what is the process?"*

   As an alternative, first [download](http://gparted.org/download.php) and burn a [GPartEd CD](http://gparted.org/) (or write to a thumb drive).  Before running the installer, boot `GPartEd` and partition the disk to your liking and run `fsck` or just run `badblocks` at length.

   When you run the Debian installer, just tell it how to use the partitions that are there.  The installer does not need to create its own partitions.  It is perfectly happy to use existing partitions.
2. *"Does fsck have a setting to control how aggressively blocks are marked as bad? If so, what is it? If not, then what can be used?"*

   The `-c` option to `e2fsck` causes it to run the `badblocks` program to scan for bad blocks.  You can run badblocks directly as well.  By default, `badblocks` does a read-only test.  To be more aggressive, you can specify `-n` for a non-destructive read-write test.  You can also set the `-p` option to increase the number of passes that it makes.

   You may want to run `badblocks` before you partition.  That way, you can specify the faster `-w` write-only test.

Comment: John, +1, just curious does `badblocks` has any method to mark on a hardware level, or just on the FS level?

Comment: @heemayl My understanding is that, on _modern_ hard disks, the hard disk's firmware attempts to do all of its own bad block management.  The purpose of running `badblocks` is merely to force the hard disk to read/write all sectors.  The hard disk does it own detection and remapping of bad sectors and, if all works as it should, the `badblocks` program is never informed that the hard disk is doing this.

Comment: hmmm..understandable. So in essence, fsck can mark blocks on FS but badblocks just help the disk firmware to to do the marking, does not do anything of its own?

Comment: @heemayl In olden times, `badblocks` would spit out a list of bad sectors and the filesystem would make note of them.  In modern times, `badblocks`  and the FS still try to do that but, with a modern HD, the list is usually empty.

Comment: @heemayl, and if the list *isn't* empty, the disk is usually so badly broken that your best option is to replace it.

Comment: The list could easily be non-empty if you're doing a non-destructive test and there's already unrecoverable data loss - some blocks will show up as unreadable.

Comment: what does it mean by `non-destructive read-write` ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Non-destructive read-write means that the contents of the sector are read and saved, then the sector is written to and tested, then the original contents are restored.  Thus, if all goes well, all the files on the disk are unchanged after the test is over.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting fsck errors that often, the drive may as well be coughing up blood. Even if you mark every single bad block as bad, it won't be long before more blocks go bad. I would imagine you could change into another tty to do an fsck if you really need to (Ctrl + alt + F2 to switch to tty2), but I can't emphasize enough how much you need a new hard drive if what you are saying is accurate.

Comment: *"If you are getting fsck errors that often..."* - what I am not sure about is, are the handful of `fsck` problems after the reinstall the extent of the problem, or is it the tip of the iceberg. The system boots, encounters a few filesystem errors (4 or 6), recovers by remounting as read-only, and then boots.

Comment: @jww can you please post some exact examples of said filesystem errors?

Comment: Why switch to another tty?    What advantage does doing so provide?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 it sounded like he couldn't open a terminal window, so switching to another tty would be the next best way to get into a shell.

Comment: @jww: Are the same blocks reported every time, or are a new set reported on each boot?

Comment: HP's Drive Protection System (DPS) Self-test recommended replace the drive. The replacement only costs $12 USD, so I ordered a new one. I don't know the extent of the problems after the OS reinstall. I could not get the tools to provide the information.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, and I don't think it's worth it. Fsck (as implemented by most filesystems) does not check your drives. It validates the filesystem metadata and makes sure the view is consistent when you mount them. It doesn't make much sense to do it before installation, because by definition, you'll only have empty space.
2. Use [badblocks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Badblocks) instead. If you want to make sure your data doesn't rot, use a filesystem which supports scrubbing. Lvm itself [can do it too](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/raid-scrub.html).

Answer (score 3):

To check a modern disk for reliability, consider using the built in tests; you can trigger them with the smartctl utility, eg:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sdx
#wait an hour or two
smartctl -a /dev/sdx
#should have recorded a result in the self-test log
```

If you want to make sure beforehand that everything has recently been written to, in order to discover sectors that will not write properly, you could overwrite the whole medium with something like a dd from /dev/urandom, or shred with one of the randomizing options.

Comment: Note that a `dd` from `/dev/random` will take many days to complete on a 500GB drive.

Comment: fixed typo, thx :) Didn't want to spell out the exact dd syntax since I wanted to avoid having command lines around that, if accidentally pasted into a shell, will cause truly irrecoverable data loss.

Comment: Unfortunately, Debian does not appear to provide `smartctl`: ***`E: Unable to locate package smartctl`***. Is it a Red Hat/Fedora utility?

Comment: debian/ubuntu package is smartmontools. BTW, use apt-cache search to search for which package has something.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend getting the manufacturer's low-level format software (if any exists) which may only run on Windows (or if you're lucky, from a bootable CD/DVD/USB for which you'd download an image from their website).  If you have sufficient control over the operation to reduce the reported capacity of the drive in exchange for a much larger spare sector pool, you should do so, in anticipation of many of those spares being substituted as you test the drive as @rackandboneman has suggested.  Far better to have a 400- or 450-GB drive with all bad sectors swapped for spares and more left for future defects, than to exhaust the spare pool and have future bad sectors that can't be transparently remapped.

Comment: I was able to run [SeaTools for DOS](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/). SeaTools reported SMART *did not* trigger, which seemed unusual. The *long test* and *short test* failed immediately. I resized the disk down to 32 GB; and then ran the long test again. SeaTools found 4 bad LBAs around the 1190000 mark and repaired them. A fresh OS install went perfectly; and subsequent reboots had no trouble. Since I purchased the replacement SATA II drive, I'll keep it as a hot spare if the existing drive misbehaves.

Comment: @jww pity that you've already accepted a different answer.

Comment: Yeah, its the Q&A trap... I have to ask specific questions to get a precise answer. If I would have asked, "how do I install Linux on a failing hard drive", then the question probably would have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic things if you don't have fancier tools available (eg it's a USB disc and SMART doesn't work):

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/null bs=1M
```

will read all of the disc.  You'll see in the `dmesg` log if there are sectors which couldn't be read.  Though it won't tell you if it managed to read them after retries.  It's not as good as `badblocks` but I mention it for its ubiquity.

If you have bad sectors and you don't want anything on the disc:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

will cause all the blocks to be rewritten.  If there are sectors which are unreadable, this should cause them to be swapped with sectors in the reallocated pool and become usable again.

If you have a disc where reallocation is happening then the disc is on the way out.  I wouldn't use it for anything important, but sometimes you have data you don't care that much about and it might be OK for that.

If it's an SSD then things are different and these don't apply.